# Error while refresh control in swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, appdelegate, uirefreshcontrol

I am trying to implement refresh control in tableview by using `UIRefreshControl`.

But while pulling for refresh in the app, it just give me a error:

> "Thread 1 : Signal SIGABRT" in the app delegate file.

I don't know how to resolve it. I need help. Can anyone tell me how to resolve this.

Below is my implemented code:

```
class FeedTableViewController: UITableViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, NSXMLParserDelegate {

var myFeed : NSArray = []
var url: NSURL = NSURL()

var tableViewCtrl = UITableViewController()

var refreshCtrl:UIRefreshControl!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tableView.rowHeight = 100
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
    self.tableView.delegate = self

    // value of the url comes from view controller swift file
    loadNews(url);
    self.refreshCtrl = UIRefreshControl()
    self.refreshCtrl!.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to refresh")
    self.refreshCtrl!.addTarget(self, action: "ref", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    self.tableView.addSubview(refreshCtrl!)


}

func ref(sender:AnyObject)
{
    loadNews(url)
    self.refreshCtrl.endRefreshing()
}

func loadNews(data: NSURL) {
            var myParser : XmlParserManager = XmlParserManager.alloc().initWithURL(data) as! XmlParserManager
    myFeed = myParser.feeds
            tableView.reloadData()
}
}
```

Comment: change this line  self.refreshCtrl!.addTarget(self, action: "ref", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged) as  self.refreshCtrl!.addTarget(self, action: "ref:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)

Comment: Oh. Hell!!! btw..... Thanks anish Parajuli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your `func ref` has a parameter, you need to add `:` when you add the target to the refresh control as below:

```
self.refreshCtrl!.addTarget(self, action: "ref:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
```